# Not able to access .DBF file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am not able read .dbf file in asp.net.

Error : External table is not in the expected format.

```
 1)  Using OLEDB

      OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\VisualFoxproDB;Extended Properties=dBASE 5.0;");
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID,NAME FROM table.dbf", conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                        gv1.DataSource = dt;
                        gv1.DataBind();
                        conn.Close();
```

.

```
2. Using ODBC   

     OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)};DriverId=277;SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=D:\\VisualFoxproDB\\;Exclusive=No");     
                            conn.Open();
                            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM D:\\VisualFoxproDB\\test.dbf";
                            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
                            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                            adapter.Fill(ds);
                            return ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Try creating a DSN to access the data.

Comment: Dear is not working.... Please help me to short out this

Comment: Done with vfpoledb

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Pl. make sure you have proper Providers.